# Twitter Typeahead Ajax, id and name

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter, typeahead.js

I try to use Twitter Typeahead with a Ajax request.
The request operate properly.

**Example result :**

```
[
    {"id":14841,"name":"Seyssinet-Pariset"},
    {"id":14985,"name":"Damparis"},
    {"id":25067,"name":"Le Touquet-Paris-Plage"},
    {"id":29427,"name":"Paris-l\u0027H\u00f4pital"},
    {"id":30438,"name":"Paris"},
    {"id":31668,"name":"Villeparisis"},
    {"id":33294,"name":"Parisot"},
    {"id":33531,"name":"Parisot"},
    {"id":36031,"name":"Fontenay-en-Parisis"},
    {"id":36126,"name":"Cormeilles-en-Parisis"}
]
```

**Js code :**

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 3
},
{
    name: 'name',
    source: function (query, process) {
         return $.get('/app_dev.php/autocomplete-city', { query: query }, function (data) {
              return process(data);
        });
    }
});
```

But the rendering is not working. There is no mistake. However nothing is displayed . I do not have a drop down menu.

My goal is to display the name fields in the drop down menu and retrieve the id in the selection.
But I do not see how...

Thanks

Comment: Can you check your developer tools console ( `F12` in Chrome) and see if there is any error?

Comment: No error. But in "Network" tab there are the requests (code 200. Ok)

Comment: Are you trying this plugin : https://github.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead I guess you need to give ajax source in a different `option` and not in source.